# Why does the iPhone Simulator show parts of the springboard behind the app?

Tags: iphone, cocos2d-iphone, ios-simulator, box2d

While revising one of my apps to work with the latest iPhone dimensions I noticed the simulator was (wrongly) displaying icons behind the app like the app wasn't sized correctly for the new 1136 x 640 dimensions.  I couldn't find anywhere in my Cocos2d 2.0 code that affected this issue and changing the size of the white background image did nothing.  When I told the simulator to go "Home" and then relaunched the app, it appeared normal.  This only happened when testing localization languages like German in the following image.

[image: The Rota Period, Rota's Periodic Table for Chemistry]

Comment: I notice from the icons that this isn't the latest version of iOS. Does the problem still occur in iOS 7 simulator?

Comment: Well, I was testing 5.0, 5.1, 7.0, Retina, non-Retina, so am not sure if it was okay with 7.0 (will check).  I'm inclined to think it's a Cocos2d/Box2d issue…i.e. how to resize properly because doubling the scale of the background white image had no effect.

Comment: It may have been something to do with setting the compiler to armv6 and armv7.  Before submitting it to Apple I removed the armv6 reference (no longer supported) and the issue has gone away.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like a bug to me.  Maybe report this to Apple?

Answer (score 0):

Yes this is definetly a bug, if not then apple will help

Answer (score 0):

```
Reset your simulato.
then run your project.
```

Answer (score 0):

Removing all references to armv6 eliminated this issue.